# How to install a minimal Xfce4 GUI on Ubuntu Server 16.04?

Tags: server, xfce, gui, nas

I'm building a NAS for my home with Ubuntu Server 16.04.

I would like to know what is the best way to install a very minimal Xfce4 graphical user interface on it in order to complete some frequent tasks on my server easily without using the CLI.

I thought to give the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xorg xterm xubuntu-desktop xubuntu-icon-theme menu gksu xfwm4-themes xfce4-terminal xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-datetime-plugin xfce4-power-manager xfce4-xkb-plugin xfce4-indicator-plugin xfce4-volumed firefox
```

Is that correct? Is there anything I forget or something unnecessary?

Comment: I do it just by `apt install xfce4`. Don't know if you can go more minimal but it works as GUI for my server's

Comment: Thanks @derHugo, it works much more better than my cmd line!

Answer (score 4):

if you try with

```
 sudo apt-get install xfce4 --no-install-recommends
```

and you will get a minimal instalation for ubuntu desktop xfce4

good luck

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install xfce4`. It work for me.