# Ubuntu server + (lightweight) desktop environment vs full-fat Ubuntu Desktop for raspberrypi4 project?

Tags: server, desktop-environments, raspberrypi

I am working on a project with my raspberry pi 4 that requires ROS, hence I am using Ubuntu instead of Raspberry OS. I figured it would be better for efficiency and performance to go with Ubuntu server and then install some desktop environment like xubuntu-desktop, but then I realize the huge amount of packages that need to be installed and how long the installation takes. It actually took quite longer to install xubuntu-desktop than to reflash the sd card with Ubuntu Desktop. That made me wonder if it is actually worth it to run the ubuntu server or just go directly with Desktop.

Just in case its relevant:

My pi has 4Gb of RAM and I am going to do navigation and mapping with a four-wheeled robot.

Edit:
So the only difference is that Ubuntu Desktop uses the Unity desktop environment while Xubuntu uses XFCE, which is lighter, more customizable, and easier on system resources than other desktop environments.

Comment: "That made me wonder if it is actually worth it to run the ubuntu server or just go directly with Desktop." --Opinion based. What works best for you is what works best for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a minimal Xfce4 GUI on Ubuntu Server 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/929200/how-to-install-a-minimal-xfce4-gui-on-ubuntu-server-16-04)

Comment: "*I figured it would be better for efficiency and performance to go with Ubuntu server and then install some desktop environment*" is not a valid assumption: They will be about the same. FYI: Xubuntu has it's own desktop installer.